# How do i parse JSON file into html table depending on dropdown selection using javascript?

Tags: html, json, dropdown

I have a JSON File which contains some objects. 
Would like to populate the object depending on dropdown selection .
The drop-down contains all the "Level" value and i need to display only the object which contains the "Level" value equal to the user selection .
Please see the following link

https://fiddle.jshell.net/agbpr021/

```
for (var i = 0; i < allData.length; i++) {
    var x = document.getElementById("level").value;
    if(x = allData.level)
        tr = table.insertRow(-1);
        for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
            var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
            tabCell.innerHTML = allData[i][col[j]];
        }
    }
            // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
    var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
    divContainer.innerHTML = "";
    divContainer.appendChild(table);
```

Comment: Please include your code in the question and it is usually best to include at least an attempt to answer the question on your own whether right or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the result you are looking for.  Probably a more efficient way of doing this, esp how I create the html for the table, but it should give you the desired output.

```js
function CreateTableFromJSON()
{
  // only included this so snippet would work
  allData = [
    { "Level": "a", "Country": "Unknown", "Currency": "USD" },
    { "Level": "a", "Country": "All", "Currency": "BRL" },
    { "Level": "b", "Country": "All", "Currency": "EUR" },
    { "Level": "c", "Country": "All", "Currency": "EUR" },
    { "Level": "d", "Country": "None", "Currency": "EUR" }
  ]
    
  var x = document.getElementById("Levels").value;
  var index = -1;
  for (var i = 0; i < allData.length; i++) {
      if (allData[i].Level == x)
          index= i;
  }

  var html = "";
  if (index != -1) {
      // probably a better way to do this portion
      html = "<table><thead><tr><th>Level</th><th>Country</th><th>Currency</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr>";
      html += "<td>" + allData[index].Level + "</td>";
      html += "<td>" + allData[index].Country + "</td>";
      html += "<td>" + allData[index].Currency + "</td>";
      html += "</tr></tbody></table>";
  } else {
      html = "Please make a selection";
  }

  // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
  divContainer.innerHTML = html;
}
```

```html
<p>levels</p>
<select id="Levels">
  <option value="Null" id="m">Choose level</option>
  <option value="a" id="A">a</option>
  <option value="b" id="B">b</option>
  <option value="c" id="C">c</option>
  <option value="d" id="D">d</option>
</select>
<br /><br />
<!--Button-->
<input type="button" onclick="CreateTableFromJSON()" value="Go" />
<div id="showData"></div>
<br>
```

EDIT: I wanted to mention real smart people have put together tools to handle this.  React, Vue and Angular are a few examples that have tools for this type of stuff.

EDIT: Added check for bad index in allData